# One client - many servers in embedded systems

Tags: java, networking, embedded, ip, httpserver

Let's say my Java ME program will bi used in embedded systems (some boxes with my program installed) in thousand different locations. Is there a possibility for these boxes to become a server (preferably a REST server) so that a client can connect to one and retrieve some information providing its ID number? It is a rare architecture where there are multiple servers and only one client. I suppose that IP addresses of these boxes won't remain static and it isn't possible to rely on them. So what is the right way to establish an http connection to one of these boxes?

Note: The inverse architecture is already established. So, each box is a client and can connect to a web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpliest way is to run a server which keeps current {id->ip addres} table. Each box, when turned on, tells the server its ip address. More sofisticated solutions can be found in [Peer-to-peer wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer)

Comment: A followup question: even if I know the needed IP address, will I be able to connect to it via port 80? Won't there be a router blocking connections and needing port-forwarding or something?

Comment: it depends on firewalls installed. Skype uses some tricks to bypass firewall restrictions. If firewalls are absent, nothing would block you from access to boxes, provided that servers are up and running.